# how to convert second output parameter type for calling build-in function from double to single in matlab coder?

Tags: matlab

My code as follows:

```matlab
[left,~] = ind2sub([size,size],finalIndex);
```

The warning message is following:

```
Output 2 of builtin function ind2sub is double-precision and has been cast to single-precision. The code generated for the builtin function may still contain doubles.
```

Line 9 give another error message:

```
[![Calls to builtin functions via function handles will not be converted to single-precision. Consider creating handle to your own function that calls the builtin.][1]][1]
```

[image: error message]

variable type information:
[image: variable type information]

I want to fix the warning message. How to cast the second out parameter?

full function code

```
function [isDuplicate,lineLeft] = check_similar_line(nAngle,nDistance)
%UNTITLED21 delete duplicate line angle < pi/180*4 and distance to
%original<4
%   input
%   output
%   1、isDuplicate
%   2、lineLeft,index of line left
size = int16(length(nAngle));
angleDifference = abs(triu(bsxfun(@minus,nAngle,nAngle'),-1)) + tril(inf(size,size));
distanceDifference = single(abs(triu(bsxfun(@minus,nDistance,nDistance'),-1)) + tril(inf(size,size)));
angleIndex = int32(find(angleDifference<pi/180*4));
% distanceDifference(index)
distanceIndex = int32(find(distanceDifference(angleIndex) < 4));
finalIndex = int32(angleIndex(distanceIndex));
[left,~] = ind2sub([size,size],finalIndex);
lineLeft = setdiff(1:size,left);
isDuplicate = ~isempty(finalIndex);
end
```

Comment: What is the value of `size`? Can you show a bit more code? What version of matlab are you using? I can't reproduce the warning on my 2022a version.
Also I assume `size` is your variable but in matlab you shouldn't name them by that name because you're shadowing the native size function

Comment: I have copied the full function. coder set size to single.

Comment: Could you just remove the `single` on the third line? Or does that break the code?

Comment: The third line's "single" has been removed. it was added for responding to coder's warning message before.

Comment: So you still have the warning?

Comment: Still have warning message, the message show to the change the build-in function @minus. it is trouble.

Comment: Yeah I really can't reproduce the warning. Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I have added warnning page, variable page in the above.

Comment: Hi @ChenYu,

I tried reproducing this issue in R2022a using the following command, but I am not seeing these warnings:

`codegen -config:mex -args {single(0), single(0)} check_similar_line`

Can you share the following information:

1) Which version of MATLAB are you using?
2) What command / script are you using to generate code?

Cheers!

Comment: R2021a is used now. When using codegen command not UI wizard, the warning message has't shown. Maybe the parameters not same.

Comment: It seems like some configuration that you've set is resulting in these warnings. You can try generating a `codegen` script from your MATLAB Coder Project to see which default configurations are being overridden: https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2021a/coder/ug/generate-a-matlab-script-to-build-a-project.html. If you need more help, please post the generated `codegen` script on your original question and I can take a look